# ServiceStack IRedisClient ScanAllKeys with a pattern does not return results as expected (ServiceStack 5.7.0)

Tags: .net, redis, servicestack

I have tried the following code with and without the '*' wildcard using IRedisClient from StackService.Redis. It does not return the list of keys that match a pattern as I expected. I am trying to search for any keys that contain the value stored in the searchPattern variable but no results are returned. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

```
using var cache = BuildClient();
cacheKeyList = cache.ScanAllKeys($"*{searchPattern}*").Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ScanAllKeys` pattern provided to the method is the pattern to match the *keys*, not the values that the keys hold.

For example if you are storing keys with the pattern `users:{id}` where `{id}` is replaced with the ID for the user, eg `users:1`, a scan for `users:*` will return all keys matching the stored users.

Underneath this method is calling the Redis SCAN command, [more info can be found in their documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scan).